# Signed by trusted CA Java Applet is not accepted by Java security

Tags: java, security, applet

Java Applet is signed by Comodo and looks fine. It starts as per picture:

I am not allowed to post pictures so I will try to describe it. The Java Applet starts and it says, "the publisher name is verified and the digital signature for this application was generated with a certificate from a trusted authority"

but when I press on "run" the following is popped up straight away:

"The publisher name is unknown. There is no digital signature for this application."

and the security warning as per picture above pops up all the time the applet is accessed / started. I tried cleaning Java cache and browsers' cache but no joy. I also tried re-installing Java completely to make it thoroughly clean "vanilla" but no dice either. The certificates are not expired, their validity is up to March 2016. I even tried importing the certs into Java's keystore but it did not help. Java is version 8 update 45 (build 1.8.0_45-b15) and it's run on Windows 8. Could anybody suggest anything, please as I am completely lost... Many thanks in advance!

In other words in order to get to the applet I have to click through the warning **each time** the applet is accessed..